# can't able to run react-native app in Android device

Tags: react-native

hai every one i am trying to run the react-native android app in device then it throws an error like as mentioned below[image]

can any one please give me suggestions for how to solve this error,Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try following the steps on the [guide page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-your-app-to-connect-to-the-local-dev-server-via-wi-fi).

You may have to set the address of your dev server.

> ## Configure your app to connect to the local dev server via Wi-Fi
>
> 1. Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
> 2. Open your React Native app on your device. You can do this the same way you'd open any other app.
> 3. You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. The following steps will fix that.
> 4. Open the Developer menu by shaking the device or running adb shell input keyevent 82 from the command line.
> 5. Go to Dev Settings.
> 6. Go to Debug server host for device.
> 7. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081). On Mac, you can find the IP address in System Preferences / Network. On Windows, open the command prompt and type ipconfig to find your machine's IP address (more info).
> 8. Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.